# S-plane transfer function contour

Tags: transfer-function, nyquist-plot

In Razavi's textbook, the following contour plots for the transfer function \$H(s)=A_0\frac{1+s/ \omega_z}{1+s/\omega_p}\$ are given. It's stated that \$H(\sigma_N) > H(\sigma_M)\$. How is this possible when the input moves further away from the pole and closer to the zero?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no input, the transfer function is evaluated at \$s=\sigma+j\omega\$ in the whole complex plane. The angle gets positive because the imaginary part, \$j\omega\$, is positive, and \$\mathrm{atan2}(\Im>0,\Re)>0\$ (when the real part is negative, there's a phase jump). And since a picture is worth a thousand words, here's how the graph evolves for:

$$H(s)=\dfrac{s+2}{s+3}$$

[image: graph]

The contour is not closed because I wanted to make the directions more clear. The black trace is the contour of \$s\$, the green is the evaluation of \$H(s)\$, the blue bullet is the pole, and the red circle is the zero. The evaluation starts at \$s=-1.625\$ and continues in clockwise direction (so first it goes negative). The evaluation has its first value at \$H(s)=0.2727...\$, and the direction is counter-clockwise (therefore it, too, goes negative first). It's easy to verify, you don't even need to follow the exact numbers I used. Here's a quick test for some round numbers (same values for the pole and the zero):

$$\begin{align}
&H(-1)&=\;&\dfrac{-1+2}{-1+3}&=\;&0.5 \tag{1} \\
&H(-2-j)&=\;&\dfrac{-2-j+2}{-2-j+3}&=\;&0.5-j0.5 \tag{2} \\
&H(-4)&=\;&\dfrac{-4+2}{-4+3}&=\;&2 \tag{3} \\
&H(-2+j)&=\;&\dfrac{-2-j+2}{-2-j+3}&=\;&0.5+j0.5 \tag{4} \\
\end{align}$$

Which tells you that:

- (1) \$\omega_z<\Re{(s)}<0\; ,\;\Im{(s)}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\Re{(H(s))}>0\; ,\;\Im{(H(s))}=0\$
- (2) \$\Re{(s)}<0\; ,\;\Im{(s)}<0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\Re{(H(s))}>0\; ,\;\Im{(H(s))}<0\$
- (3) \$\Re{(s)}<\omega_p<0\; ,\;\Im{(s)}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\Re{(H(s))}>0\; ,\;\Im{(H(s))}=0\$
- (4) \$\Re{(s)}<0\; ,\;\Im{(s)}>0\quad\Rightarrow\quad\Re{(H(s))}>0\; ,\;\Im{(H(s))}>0\$

What's different from the book is the direction of the evaluation of \$H(s)\$. They're showing that the directions go bith CW, while here they're mirrored, but their maginary values are the same: both positive or negative. Maybe I missed something, I'll look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. By "input" I meant the specific values of s along their contour on the left on which H gets evaluated to produce the contour on the right. In any case, I think that your results actually agree with what I was wondering about, since it seems like you start from a point close to the zero and then move around to the side closer to the pole, and the magnitude of your H increases in the process. I checked the book errata and this isn't listed, so I'm not sure if I'm still missing something or maybe the errata isn't updated...

Comment: Furthermore, I modified some Matlab code by Brian Douglas to do interactive contour plotting of H(s)=(s+2)/(s+3). You can see it here, but if you don't trust a stranger's pastebin code I don't blame you: https://pastebin.com/raw/YfjDt0rq In any case, it matches your plot and confirms what you said about the direction being mirrored. I believe this happens because while the book says the value increases from M to N, actually it decreases, and so the direction gets reversed.

Comment: Picture of what the interactive plotting looks like: https://i.imgur.com/Q17OXln.png

Comment: @knzy I don't have Matlab and Octave complains that the function `impoint()` is not yet implemented (though it does plot a "fixed" version). So for confirmation, I've made [these plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni7GA.png). You can clearly see the evolution. Maybe there's an explanation further in the book, somewhere. If not, it's possible they've accidentally mirrored the image. But it is misleading to say that \$H(\sigma_N)>H(\sigma_M)\$, because it's the opposite. Well, now you have the proof in front of you, and I suppose worse things have happened.